How to integrate client side Sentry tracing with Micrometer and OpenTelemetry in a Spring Boot backend application
I am maintaing a Spring Boot 3 application (ca classic Spring MVC application, no Spring Web Flux). This application uses Micrometer and OpenTelemetry to gather metrics and tracing information. For every request a separate trace and spans are generated on the server side.
Now, a client (mobile app, which I do not maintain) uses Sentry to generate tracinf information and therefore sends a Sentry Trace and Baggage as HTTP headers to the Spring Boot application, eg:
baggage: sentry-trace_id=c9d8fd62bef842f812d1f1d685c95985-f54e0d0ac29c4e5a,sentry-public_key=ABC123,sentry-release=com.acme.test%400.1.38%2B8363,sentry-environment=test
sentry-trace: c9d8fd62bef842f812d1f1d685c95985-f54e0d0ac29c4e5a

To improve troubleshooting I want to use the client side generated Sentry Trace and/or Baggage on the server side, too. As a fallback, it would be OK to 'link' the information sent by the client to the Traces / Spans generated on the server side.
As I understood the documentation this should be done with 'Context Propagation'. Unfortunately, I don't know how this is supposed to work. What would help is an explanation how Context Propagation works and where it has  to be integrated in a Spring Boot application.

I think the easiest would be sentry sending the data in a standardized format (B3 or W3C) not in a custom format that they made up (I assume).
If you check the properties and the auto-configuration of Boot, it let's you choose multiple formats. You can add your own propagator and implement Sentry's logic next to what is already configured (B3, W3C).

Thanks for the hint. I will try to set up a test if it would work that way.
